# Is there a limit to the number of instance we can feed to DrawIndexedInstanced

Tags: graphics, 3d, directx, directx-12

I am implementing instancing inside my DirectX 12 renderer. I was wondering.
Is there a limit to the number of instance we can feed to ID3D12GraphicsCommandList::DrawIndexedInstanced?
If that limit is reached, what will happen. Will directX split the call to smaller batches?